# activity indicator only animates once

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

i have created a custom "load more" cell at the bottom of my table view. And am trying to animate a activity indicator while the table is being populated with 5 more rows. Because the data loads too quickly, i have put a 2 sec timer to delay the process and want to show the indicator animation.

I seem to be able to get the indicator animated once then it wont animate any more, however the rest of the code still executes and works fine.

here is my code for when user selects the cell...

```
[moreCellIndicator startAnimating];           

//setup activity indicator timer
NSTimer *activityTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                                      target: self
                                                    selector:@selector(loadMoreTimer:)
                                                    userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

here is the code that triggers after the timer...

```
- (void) loadMoreTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer {   

    //stop animating activity indicator
    [moreCellIndicator stopAnimating];

    //refresh table
    ... data gets reloaded

}
```

for some reason the first time the code is run the indicator will animate, but any more presses and it wont animate.

any help would be appreciated.

chris

edit: moreCellIndicator is declared like so...

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *moreCellIndicator;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *moreCellIndicator;
```

Comment: I check your code and it works perfectly,and yes don't initialize it again,just implement [spinner startAnimating]; and  [spinner stopAnimating];

Answer (score 0):

Try to `release` the activity indicator after you stop it, and initialize it before you start it:

```
moreCellIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
```

and instead of using `NSTimer` use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadMoreTimer:) withObject:self afterTimeDelay:2];
```

And change your method to `(id):sender`

```
- (void)loadMoreTimer:(id)sender
```

Comment: when i initialise it before i tell it to animate it just disappears completely. no idea whats going on???